# Claims values returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my web application, Account controller Login action I wrote a code to determine if user names and passwords are correct and load some data to the claims.

The issue is when debugging the code line by line it shows data adding to the claims, but when I tried to retrieve it, it returned null.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the Code

```
public void SignInUser(string username, string userRole, string userid, bool isPersistent, string UserLevel,
  string User_Company, string EmpName, string DepId) {
  // Initialization.    
  var claims = new List < Claim > ();
  try {
    // Setting    
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
    claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", userid));
    claims.Add(new Claim("UserLevel", UserLevel));
    claims.Add(new Claim("CompanyID", User_Company));
    claims.Add(new Claim("EmpName", EmpName));
    claims.Add(new Claim("DepId", DepId));

    var claimIdenties = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
    // Sign In.    
    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() {
      IsPersistent = isPersistent
    }, claimIdenties);
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    // Info    
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

This is how I retrieved the data from claims

```
var UsrLvl = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserLevel").FirstOrDefault();
var UsrID = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserId").FirstOrDefault();
var UserDep = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "DepId").FirstOrDefault();
```

This is how data is passed

[image]

But when retrieving it's null

[image]

Comment: `UsrLvl` and `UserDep` are not `null`?

Comment: @Me3nTaL All data that are added to the claims return null when retriving

Comment: Try to access the Claims by your `claimsPrincipal`, e.g. `claimsPrincipal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "UserId")`

Comment: @Me3nTaL Thanks. But an issue. If I call this ``UserId`` from another controller ``claimsPrincipal`` not found. How to avoid this?

Comment: Use `var claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal` elsewhere in your application.

Comment: @Me3nTaL No dear. It's not working. There is another project that uses the same method I used. It getting data. But here in my program same way no data.

Comment: When you set your `ClaimsPrincipal` in the `HttpContext.User` you can access it application-wide.

Comment: @Me3nTaL Still didn't work. By the way, this is a combination of ``2 contexts``. I check the ``user name`` and the ``password`` ``context 1`` and add those data to the claims and then ``redirect it to the 2nd project``. Will this is the problem?